# QGis Application Debugging - missing source problem at setScene method in QgsMapCanvas class

Tags: qgis, c++, qgs

I develop a app in C++ with Qgis components with VS2010 Prof on Windows 7. Compiling a release succeeded and the app´s behaviour is as expected. Nevertheless I would like to take advantage of the debug mode for further modifications. I get an an unhandled exception in the nt.dll, missing source, whenever the debugger comes to the `setScene(mScene)` method. I made a folder with all available '*.cpp' files from the QT4 and the QGis source files, so all sources should be available. Does anybody know which source file might be missing at this point?

Comment: The sources that are "missing" are from a system library on Windows and would not help you to solve your problem. As it currently stands, this question can only be answered by the company that compiles Windows :) I would propose to rephrase the question to focus on your real problem.